# Cocos2d texture memory usage

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using cocos2d and have a 1024x1024 spritesheet.

I load the texture in RGBA4444 format and it consumes 2MB marked as 'gfxAllocateTextureLevel'.

Then when I create CCSprites from the spritesheet it instantly consumes an extra 4MB of memory marked as glsmLoadTextureLevelBuffer.

So 6MB in total, which is quite a lot relative to my app. Is this expected? Does it need to create such a buffer for every spritesheet or even CCSpriteBatchNode? Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating the CCSprites? are you using initWithSpriteSheet?

Comment: I create a sprite with [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName@"spr.png"] I load the spritesheet itself with: [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImageAsync:@"x.png" target:self selector:@selector(gameSpritesLoaded:)]; Then add them to the cache before creating a batch node: [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"x.plist"];

Answer (score 1):

[OpelGLES1.1 Spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf) states:

> "The GL stores the resulting texture with internal component resolutions of its own choosing"

=>the GPU/driver may convert your pixels up in size as needed by the GPU (GPU may only natively operate on certain pixel formats, so anything that isn't that will be made into one), so I think you have 2MB of RGBA4444, and 4MB of RGBA8888 of the same sprite sheet.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I follow. What might I be doing wrong to make it load it in both pixel formats?

Comment: The gfxAllocateTextureLevel is the RGBA4444. However, before the GPU can use it, it must be prepare for GPU usage, which involves a conversion RGBA8888(the GPU native format).

Comment: But then what would be the point in ever using RGBA4444 format?

Comment: What's the point in any particular bitmap format - probably storing an image with the smallest amount of bits required. OpenGL ES doesn't let you know what the internal GPU format is. However, you can cheat because AFAICT, every instance of an implementation (all iPhones + IOS5) have the same GPU format, so you can make it match that way if you want. Each GPU has different formats it is better or worse at.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem! 
I load the texture in RGBA8888 format and it consumes 4MB marked as 'gfxAllocateTextureLevel'.

Then when I create CCSprites from the spritesheet it instantly consumes an extra 4MB of memory marked as glsmLoadTextureLevelBuffer.